# How to Intent web browser when Click Firebase Notification on android?

Tags: android, firebase

I want when I click Firebase Notification,
start Web Browser.

in my situation. When I Click Firebase Notification,
show Web Browser, but Immediately show `SplashActivity`

`SplashActivity` -> `Web Browser` -> `SplashActivity`

I want `SplashActivity`  -> `Web Browser` (finish)

Why do I see my web browser and see my previous activity again?

notification.class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(SHOW_BROWSER_URL, url);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

....(notificationManager setting)...
```

SplashActivity.class (onCreate)

```
String notificationType = getIntent().getStringExtra(Notification.SHOW_BROWSER_URL);

if (notificationType.equal(SHOW_BROWSER_URL) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

If possible, how to Without going through the activity,
when notification click, immediately show browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your notification class (I'm assuming the class which subclasses FirebaseMessageHandler) you're creating an Intent to start a SplashScreen Activity. Just don't do this. Instead, open a webbrowser intent.

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
```

Do note: when the app is NOT active, the notification is sent to the notification tray and instead. The starting activity contains the Intent with data from FCM.

Comment: because we have to do related work on SplashActivity

Comment: It's bad practice to put actual important code you want to run into a SplashActivity. Use a subclass of Application instead. Read here what launch screens are: https://material.io/design/communication/launch-screen.html#branded-launch Read here how to PROPERLY use "Splash Activities" https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/ and read here about Applications subclass https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class